# CSS: Change color of div during animation of another one

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to change the color of a div for the time another div goes through its animation. I already got my html file ready:

```css
   .body {
      width: 1200px;
      background-color: white;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 50px;
    }

    .bar {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 0.1;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      width: 500px;
      height: 25px;
      left: 100px;
      top: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      animation-name: expandBar;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-delay: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    @keyframes expandBar {
      from {
          width: 0px;
      }
      to {
          width: width;
      }
    }

    .box {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 0.1;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      top: 135px;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="de">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bc.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

For starters, I tried using following code to test how this works (I've seen that on the internet). Works fine.

```
.bar:hover ~ .box{
  background-color: red;
}
```

However, I now don't know how to adress the animation of the bar element. I want the box to be red during the 2 seconds the bar expands.

Is there something like a keyword instead of hover I could use for that? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't directly think of a solution only using CSS. But a little javascript might help. There is `onanimationstart` and `onanimationend` that might help you. [Link to MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend)

Below a working example.

```js
let bar = document.getElementById("bar")
let box = document.getElementById("box")

bar.onanimationstart = function(event){
  box.classList.add("red")
}

bar.onanimationend = function(event){
  box.classList.remove("red")
}
```

```css
#body {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
}

#bar {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: expandBar;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes expandBar {
  from {
      width: 0px;
  }
  to {
      width: width;
  }
}

#box {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 135px;
  position: absolute;
}

.red{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bc.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works! And I'm perfectly fine with using js in addition for it to do so. One question though. Could you explain why you're using #bar and #box in the css instead of the period? I learned it with a period, but when I change that it stops working.

Comment: Sure. I used the element id as selector for convenience. Because when getting the element by className, there might be found multiple instances and I would have to access to element with an index.
You can read more here: [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) and [getElementByClassName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@keyframes expandBar {
  from {
      width: 0px;
  }
  to {
      width: width;
background:red;
  }
}
```

and add
`transition:2s` in the .bar styling.

Comment: What's that supposed to do? Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you try this?

Comment: I want the box to be red not the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate the color change in your css @keyframes animation.

```
@keyframes changeBox {
  0% {  background-color: red; }
  99.99% { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: cornflowerblue;  }
}
.box {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.1;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 135px;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: changeBox;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```